why std::is_same<int, *(int*)>::value is false?
Should *(int*) be just int in C++11?
I run compile below code with g++ -std=c++11, it outputs "0", which is out of my expectation.
int num = 0;                       
int *num_ptr = &num;               
cout<<std::is_same<decltype(num), decltype(*num_ptr)>::value<<endl;//0


*num_ptr gives you int&.

It's silly, but template<class> void f()=delete; is a very useful way to have a compiler actually tell you what a type is (here, via f<decltype(*num_ptr)>()).

@康桓瑋 That is incorrect.  When you dereference a pointer you get an lvalue of the pointed to type, not a reference, it is just that decltype adds the reference to reflect that it is an lvalue.  That is for built in types.

Try std::remove_reference<decltype(*num_ptr)>::type

you usually need std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(expression)> to get a pure type

@DavisHerring Alternatively, tools like clangd are able to provide inlay hints with such things.

@DavisHerring Not silly at all, of such tricks are seasoned programmers made

@NathanOliver -- is there a test that would distinguish between the expression *i being an lvalue or lvalue reference? Or is it a distinction without difference?

@Gene I can't think of a way to differentiate between the two.  It's just that if you read the standard it explicitly states its not a reference type for built in types.  That said any way of checking that I know of would materialize a reference type.

@NathanOliver -- this question piqued my curiosity, the only place in the standard I found where built-in unary operator* is described is here returning reference: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.built#5

@Gene See: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.unary.op#1

@NathanOliver -- yeah, that's interesting. So how do you harmonize those two passages? The way they chose words is also interesting, the operator yields rather than returns.

@Gene [over.built] only deals with overload resolution. It is only relevant in the context of deciding whether or not the built-in * operator will be used. [expr.unary.op] determines the behavior for the built-in * specifically. But there is no meaningful distinction. An expression can't have a reference type. An expression only has a value category. In case an overload is chosen, the function returning returning an lvalue reference is completely equivalent with the function call expression being an lvalue expression. There is nothing to differentiate.

@user17732522 -- thanks for explanation, just my curiosity, hopefully it's interesting to others as well.

To add to the confusion, is_same<decltype((num)), decltype(*num_ptr)::value is true.

Dupe: c++ why decltype(*pointer) yields a reference?

Besides types, decltype also considers value categories.
For id-expression, i.e. num, decltype leads to its type which is int.
For *num_ptr, which is an lvalue-expression, decltype leads to T& i.e. int&.


If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression or an
unparenthesized class member access expression, then decltype yields
the type of the entity named by this expression.

If the argument is any other expression of type T, and
a) if the value category of expression is xvalue, then decltype yields
T&&;
b) if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields
T&;
c) if the value category of expression is prvalue, then decltype
yields T.




And an "id-expression" is essentially a variable name. Everything else falls through to the second case.

@HolyBlackCat Plus function names and the explicitly mentioned exception for member access of the form decltype(a.b), decltype(a->b) and other forms. Also directly named members of classes, e.g. decltype(class::member), even if they are non-static, which is usually otherwise only allowed when forming a member pointer.

The type of an identifier in a declaration is determined by not just the class of the identifier but also the value category of the identifier. Songyuanyao's answer has some credible reference for that.
I would also add that std::is_same also considers the C-V qualification of an identifier in addition to value category. In other words:
T, const T, const T&, T&&, volatile T, volatile T& e.t.c are not the same types.
